# Can not COPY data between two DBs

Tags: php, mysql, vps

I have an app that uses PHP and MySQL in some sections.

Recently, my ISP was giving me lots of trouble and then I decided to change to a VPS to have more control of the system.

I have installed on this VPS everything my App needs to work (MySQL, php, apache, phpmyadmin) everything is working fine.

I started to move the databases and PHP files to the VPS and made the necessary changes to the PHP files to access the new DBs, user, password, etc...

Using the PHP files, I managed to read and write on the DBs, but I could not COPY data between two DBs or DELETE data.

When I give the copy and delete commands thru PHPMyAdmin's console it is working, but when I do the same thing via PHP it does not.

This exact code is working perfectly on the older server... what can be wrong?

This is my code:

```
<?php
ini_set('default_charset','UTF-8');
$con=mysqli_connect("url","user","pass","db_name");
mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf8");

if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{
   echo '{"query_result":"ERROR"}';
}

$emp_id = $_GET['id'];

$result = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO publiagenda
        SELECT * FROM moderagenda WHERE id = $emp_id
        DELETE * FROM moderagenda WHERE id = $emp_id");


if($result == true) 
{
echo <<<HTML
<br><center>Dados Publicados no app e apagados da tabela de      moderacao</center></big
HTML; 

echo <<<HTML
<br><center><big><a    href="http://appdacidade.net.br/app/agenda/publish_agenda.php">Voltar</a></center></big
HTML;

}
else
{
    echo '{"query_result":"FAILURE"}';
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

***With the valuable help of the members of this community, my code is now working, following is the corrected code:***

```
<?php
ini_set('default_charset','UTF-8');
$con=mysqli_connect("url","user","pass","db_name");
mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf8");

if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{
   echo '{"query_result":"ERROR"}';
}

$emp_id = $_GET['id'];

$result = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO publiagenda
        SELECT * FROM moderagenda WHERE id = $emp_id");


if($result == true) 
{
header("Location: ./dados_publicados.html");
}
else
{
    echo '{"query_result":"FAILURE"}' . mysqli_error($con);
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: `echo '{"query_result":"FAILURE"}';` => `echo '{"query_result":"FAILURE"}' . mysqli_error($con);`

Comment: you're also trying to perform a multi-query and not using the right function for it.

Comment: `</big` - you forgot the `>` here.

Comment: `DELETE *` is incorrect, you can't delete a specific column with `delete`. It is `delete from`, no columns listed. You also are open to SQL injections.

Comment: Is the copy code not working, or this specific code? This looks to only be accessing/interacting with 1 DB.

Comment: With your help the code is now working! Thank you all! I will publish the working code in my question to help others in the same situation

Comment: @Vladimir Don't edit the question, add the updated code as an answer. This way new users will know it is now working. (Also note that your new code is still susceptible to injections and doesn't do what your old code was going to do (no delete from moderagenda))